# I cannot get div to move up

Tags: html, css

I cannot get Slogan! (id h2) to raise above the picture. h1 is perfectly fine, but not h2.
I am new to CSS, HTML, and Stackoverflow if that meens anything.
I appreciate the help in advance.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="HomePage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="Icon">
    <div id="h1">Name</div>
    <img src="RightArrow.jpg" class="img-circle">
    <div id="h2">Slogan!</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#h1{
    line-height:120px;/*to lower it*/
    position:absolute;
    left:-150px;
    font-size:38.5px;
}

#h2{
    line-height:-300px/*to raise it*/
    position:absolute;
    right:400px;
    font-size:38.5px;
}

#Icon{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    margin-left:600px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `line-height`? I know you're new to CSS, but did you look up what the style means/is? Try looking at the style `top`. You're on the right track using `position: absolute` (along with `right`)

Comment: what do you mean by above? is it above inside the image or above outside the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line height should not be used to move anything.  Use relative or absolute positioning.  However, here's a simpler solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="HomePage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="Icon">
    <div id="h1">Name</div>
    <div id="h2">Slogan!</div>
    <img src="RightArrow.jpg" class="img-circle">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly want to do???
Raise above image can be done just by

```
<div id="h2">Slogan!</div>
<img src="RightArrow.jpg" class="img-circle">
```

I am not getting what u want to do???
 Please be more specfic about your requirement...

Comment: I want to raise h2 up to the middle of the image. So it looks like Name, the image, and Slogan! are horizontally aligned. I guess that would be like a column layout correct?     Without re-positioning anything, h1 is positioned above the image and h2 is below the image.